# Can "open" be used as "available job/position"?

Tags: word-usage

In the Collins dictionary website I found the following entry (number 30) for the word "open" (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/open):

> See also opening [sense 6]

And the 6th entry for "opening" says:

> An opening is a job that is available.

The Merriam-Webster dictionary also links to "opening", though it doesn't indicate an entry (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open, entry 3.1).

Unless there's something I'm missing, this would mean one could say, for example, "that shop has an open", correct? That sounds weird to me (a non-native), though, and I haven't had luck searching for similar sentences or in other dictionaries. Is that meaning actually correct? Are there any examples of this usage?

***Please, note that in both dictionaries "open" is being used as a noun in this case, not as an adjective, and they indicate that it's a synonym of "opening" (obviously also as a noun). I'm asking about the usage of "open" as a noun.***

Comment: All of your sources say "opening"...what is the basis for substituting "open"?

Comment: @Cascabel According to the cited dictionaries, one of the meanings of "open" is a synonym of "opening", so I should be able to use "open" with that meaning. I'm asking about that particular usage of "open".

Comment: No. A *job* can be open, and you can say "that shop has an open job", but "that shop has an open" is incorrect. You can't use "open" instead of "opening" in quite that way.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not talking about the usage as an adjective, I'm talking about the usage as a noun. According to the cited dictionaries, "open" as a noun is a synonym of "opening"; Merriam-Webster doesn't specify of what specific meaning of "opening", but Collins specifies the meaning "a job that is available".

Comment: I have never heard of "open" used as a noun synonymous with "opening." I suspect the dictionaries are describing some extremely obscure or archaic usage. "That shop has an open" is unequivocally incorrect.

Comment: I know you were asking about noun usage. I was saying that that usage is incorrect (at least as far as job openings go). You're reading too much into "see also", as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what the “see also” parts mean. When you look at “sense 6” of “opening” the synonyms listed there do not include “open”. There is no indication that the dictionary thinks “open” as a noun is a synonym for “opening”. It’s just pointing you to related words that you might be interested in.

Comment: @ColleenV Indeed, I may be misunderstanding the "see also", but in the case of M-W it's clear it's saying that "opening" is a synonym, unless we assume it's a mistake, which is what is throwing me off: www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-cross-references : "A cross-reference immediately following a boldface colon is a synonymous cross-reference [...] a definition at the entry cross-referred to can be substituted as a definition for the entry or the sense or subsense". It doesn't say which specific sense of "opening", though, and I don't see any that works any better.

Comment: @Trisibo If you're asking us to correct Merriam-Webster's entry for "open" as a noun where they tell you to see "opening" but don't tell you which of the many senses of "opening" apply, that's off-topic. If you can find a thesaurus that lists "open" as a synonym for "job opening", that would be different. [M-W's thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/opening) doesn't list the "job opening" sense of "opening". If they really thought "open" was a synonym for that, they would list it there. (They could mean sense #1  commencement or #3 1st performance btw)

Comment: @ColleenV I don't think the thesaurus is exhaustive if we compare it with the dictionary, but in any case it's also off-topic and it doesn't matter, I think I was just stubbornly trying to apply their description about cross-references when actually it doesn't work like that in this case.

Answer (score 5):

"See also" **does not mean** "synonym of." It only means "here's something *related* which might interest you." Collins doesn't list any noun uses of "open" and Merriam-Webster's are all flat wrong in my opinion except sense 3 ("an open contest, competition, or tournament"). The noun form of *open* is *opening* and they are definitely not interchangeable.

Comment: It's quite probable I'm misunderstanding "see also", though in the case of Merriam-Webster it seems clear to me that it's saying that "opening" is a synonym, unless we assume it's a mistake: www.merriam-webster.com/help/explanatory-notes/dict-cross-references : "A cross-reference immediately following a boldface colon is a synonymous cross-reference [...] a definition at the entry cross-referred to can be substituted as a definition for the entry or the sense or subsense". It doesn't say which specific sense of "opening", though.

Comment: In any case, I don't see anything wrong with definitions 2 and 4 for "open" as a noun in the case of Merriam-Webster, you can say "to be in the open" which works for both cases.